# Setting CSS for IE only?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, browser

I have a simple `div` with a 2px thick border and absolute positioning thats hidden until its parent element is hovered over. Due to IEs box model, the position of said `div` is somewhat off in IE, but not any other browser. I don't want to add an entirely seperate style sheet for IE, I just want to modify the class itself if the browsing person is using IE.

So how does one modify **or** add a specific class for IE only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use something called **conditional comments**. These only work in IE (other browsers will see them as comments) so they are a great way to target IE only.

**Example** - if you want something to be done in IE6 use the following:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
Special instructions for IE 6 here
<![endif]--
```

To find out more, visit the [official MSDN source regarding conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Can I insert these comments in CSS code, or even better, directly inside the class definition?

Comment: Take a look at the source link I posted it'll show you everything, you can actually even place these comments around JavaScript if you like!

Comment: @dsg : right chevron character is missing at the end of your code (`<![endif]-->`)

Answer (score 1):

You can just add following conditional snippets at your html (or whatever) file. After that you can define new class attributes in your `ie_stylesheet.css`

```
  <!--[if IE]>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="ie_stylesheet.css"/>
  <![endif]-->
```

I think there are enough explanations [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can try and avoid the IE stylesheet by adding a CSS reset to the beginning of your stylesheet. Please take a look at the following: http://www.cssreset.com/scripts/html5-doctor-css-reset-stylesheet/

The reset should help making elements behave the same in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this usage of [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) to be a pretty elegant way of tagging your `<html>` tag with classes that you can work with in your CSS and JS:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

As a contrived example, if you want to target IE6 to make all links red, you would use specificity like this:

```
.lt-ie7 a {
  color: red;
}
```

No need for a separate style sheet.

Source: [Conditional stylesheets vs CSS hacks? Answer: Neither!](http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/)