# In a C# ASP.NET view, how can I wrap numbers after a comma?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, number-formatting

At the moment I have something that looks a little like this

> @string.Format("{0:#,###,###.##}", "9999999999")

which  will display the value as:  9,999,999,999

However sometimes I have only a small DIV to display this large number.  So I want to wrap the number after the commas.

I did try this

> @string.Format("{0:#,###,###.##}", @lot.MinDecrement).replace(",", ",< wbr>")

I just tried to see if it would but a break in the word, but this doesn't work and actually puts  in the string.

Does anyone know how I can simply make the text wrap if it needs to, after a comma?

Thanks

Comment: You don't wrap the number using formatting. Wrapping is a style, you should do it with CSS on your DIV

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea as it changes the meaning of the number, you should just move the whole number to a new line if it doesn't fit. Also, in German, commas can represent decimal points

Comment: And how can I do that after a comma, CSS doesn't recognise a comma and can't be told to wrap after a comma, it would just break the word where it has to

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the content of a DIV with CSS, like so:

```
div{
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/4s4qq/) (resize the output pane)

If you want it to wrap after each comma, then you can add spaces to the value (which may be what you was trying to do, like so:

```
@String.Format("{0:#,###,###.##}", "9999999999").Replace(",", ", ");
```

[Here is an example using this result](http://jsfiddle.net/4s4qq/1/)

Comment: This only works if there is a space in the word.  I can force it to break a word however that would just break it anywhere, I need it after a comma only

Comment: @Ben, it doesn't only work with spaces, my example proves that. Also, I have updated to show how to add spaces after each comma which gives you the effect you want

Comment: Ye but the problem is I can't have spaces after the comma's either, I needs to be a whole string.  However I found I way just now, So I will post this here now

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this by simply adding Html.Raw at the beginning on the String format.  So like this

```
@Html.Raw(string.Format("{0:#,###,###.##}", "9999999999").replace(",", ",<wbr>"))
```

This seems to work exactly how I want it,  but thanks everyone

**However - Not supported in IE**
 - Looking for another alternative

Comment: Sorry to make a big edit to your post, but I fixed so you can see the `<wbr>` without the space

Comment: Ok, as this doesn't work in IE, I have had to just go with the CSS style word-break:break-all; which will break the number in any place that it needs to without a space.  Not really what I wanted, but it will have to do.

Comment: Why don't you just do the CSS version on IE only, I think there is a CSS selector you can use for just IE? Don't use it so not sure of top of head. [Maybe this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13361015/setting-css-for-ie-only)